# Automatic/learned window placement when second screen is added

Tags: gnome, 18.04, external-monitor

I noticed that when I move a window to another screen and run it full screen (probably also if not), then remove the screen, then add the screen again, the window will move to the additional screen again.

This is cool! I wonder how and where those settings are stored and if this is configurable through configuration files in some way. I looked in `~/.config/gnome-session/saved-session/`, but it's empty. I also found `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/application_state`, but do not quite understand the format.

Where else could I look?

Comment: My guess is that it'd be in the X Window properties, but I haven't an external monitor to test it.

Comment: @NonnyMoose hopefully not yet another feature that is gone when switching to wayland.